# How to generate complex json from antd forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

Hello I would like to use Antd with ReactJS to create a Json with nested objects without having to parse the form into a interface or some other structure.

I am super new to react and antd and I thought this syntax would work, but it does not.

```
          <Form.Item name={['supplier', 'phone']} label="Telefone" >
            <Input />
          </Form.Item>
              
          <Form.Item name={['supplier.address', 'adress1']} label="Endereço">
            <Input />
          </Form.Item>      
                   
          <Form.Item name={['supplier.address', 'adress2']} label="Complemento">
            <Input />
          </Form.Item>
```

into this

```
    "phone": 1231231,
    "address": [
      {
        "adress1": "string",
        "adress2": "string"
      }]
}
```

My sender

```
javascript  const onFinish = async (values: Store) => {
    console.log(values);
    let response = await axios.post(
      'http://0.0.0.0:8080/suppliers',
      values.supplier ,
      { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }
    )
    console.log(response.data)
  };
```

But that does not send any of the address part of it, what is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Form.List to put values into array. Look at the example:
https://ant.design/components/form/#Form.List

That's how I would do it:

```
<Form initialValues={{phone: '', address: [ 'val1', 'val2' ]}}>
  <Form.Item name={'phone'} label="Telefone" >
            <Input />
  </Form.Item>
  <Form.List>
    {fields => (
      <Form.Item name={[ fields.name, 'address' + fields.name]} label="Endereço">
            <Input />
      </Form.Item>
    )}
  </Form.List>
</Form>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. It does not compile here with typescript...

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-shtern-1mb7y?file=/index.js) working example.
Basically, on `onFinish` function, I get `values` object and create the object that you want like this:

```
const onFinish = values => {
   let result = {};
   result.address = [];
   result.phone = values.phone;
   let addresses = {};
   addresses.address1 = values.address1;
   addresses.address2 = values.address2;
   result.address.push(addresses);
   console.log("Success:", result);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, so there is no other way? Because that was what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: I spent 2 hour to undestrand how to use initialValues with nested values and arrays. Read [this](https://ant.design/components/form/v3) on section Nested field paths using arrays. I didn't understand nothing... :(